# configuration postgres and pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql

I have one server database with postgresql 9.5 and pgbouncer 1.7 and there are 4 web application ( having clustering between them) and these 4 application connected to the postgresql server through the pgbouncer and this web application for remotely education.
Database server with 256 GB RAM and 64 CPU and all the querires that going from the applications to the postgresql running under user "postgres".

My big trouble that I can't received more than around 2500-2600 (in this range) users even there are more than 150,000 users on the application and I usually monitor the CPUs and RAMs but no utilization at all.

I need to know what is the best practice shall I apply for the below configurations

pgbouncer.ini:-

```
[databases]
test_db = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db 

myapp1 = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db pool_size=20  max_db_connections=20 
myapp2 = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db pool_size=20  max_db_connections=20 
myapp3 = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db pool_size=20  max_db_connections=20 
myapp4 = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db pool_size=20  max_db_connections=20 

[pgbouncer]

logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/postgresql/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = 0.0.0.0
listen_port = 5433
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql 
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres

pool_mode = transaction
server_reset_query = RESET ALL; 
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
max_client_conn = 6000
autodb_idle_timeout = 3600
default_pool_size = 64
max_db_connections = 600
max_user_connections = 400
```

Comment: "there are 4 web application...and these 4 application connected to the postgresql server through the pgbouncer"  Why?  Doesn't the app server have its own built in connection pooling?

Comment: " I can't received more than around 2500-2600 (in this range) users "  What error are you getting?

Comment: Regarding your first question please give me example or explain it in more details. Regarding your second question I don't receive any error but just the users not increase more than this range even I already have around 250,000 users registered and 150,000 of them active so I think this is related to some configurations limits the users from increasing